# UIToolbar refuses to move

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uitoolbar

I've been trying to move my `UIToolbar` on `-(void)viewDidLoad` but no matter what I use, it doesn't work. My example code is below:

```
[toolBarView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 50, 150, 150)];
[toolBarView setCenter:CGPointMake(50,50)];
```

Comment: First check if your toolbar is not nil, and second for positioning and sizes use frame property toolBarView.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,150,150).

Comment: @danypata already checked that, also I use NSLog(@"%f", toolBarView.frame.origin.y) and it says it's 50 but it doesn't show up.

Comment: It doesn't show up, you mean is not displayed or is not moved ?

Comment: @danypata sorry about that,  I meant it doesn't move on the display

Comment: Did you try to move it in `viewDidAppear` method ?

Comment: i can help you if you provide  some detail about your problem.

Comment: @BobApple please see the answer below and my comment

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926446/moving-uitoolbar

Answer (score 3):

The way I was able to do this is wait until `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` was called. When that was called I then called the below code:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [toolBarView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 50, 150, 150)];
    [toolBarView setCenter:CGPointMake(50,50)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off Auto Layout in the interface builder (not recommended but should help). Auto Layout is set to use constraints in order to position views on the screen, it will enforce their application at all the times. Any manual assignments to `frame`/`bounds`/`center` properties, will trigger a relayout, causing your changes to be overwritten. Try using `viewWillAppear` to change the `position` if that does not help.